# Confused over usage of "based"

Tags: grammar

"Underpinned by left-wing perspective,the defence gains in significance,based as it is on the development of critical art of inheritance,of combing past and present and establishing links to shape a better world."

In this sentence how the word "based" is used as i have read based on but here is nothing such.please reply

correct should have been "Underpinned by a progressive left-wing perspective, the defense gains in significance, as it is based on the development of critical art of inheritance, combing past and present and establishing links to shape a better world.". so how it is used?

Comment: "as it is" is a prepositional phrase modifying based?

Comment: can you explain it little bit please @Stuart F

Comment: The wagon wouldn't move, stuck, as it was, in the mud. The wagon wouldn't move, as it was stuck in the mud.  Different meanings. With the second sentence "as" means "because".  In the first sentence, "as" means "how".

Comment: Some people might understand  the first sentence as "... stuck, *which* it was, in the mud". As a kind of parenthetic emphatic.

Comment: Using Tim's simpler example: 'The wagon wouldn't move, stuck, as it was, in the mud' = The wagon wouldn't move, stuck (it really _was_ stuck) in the mud (apart from differing emphasis).

Comment: @thank you all.